# I am having errors in styles.xml in app theme

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, android-styles

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sammar.materialdeisgn">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="YourAppName"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And I am getting the following errors :

```
1)Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar').



 2)Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar').



 3)Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar').



 4)Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar').



 5)Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.



 > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute 

aapt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest style not referenced `NoActionBar` theme so add below lines

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

so your `Style.xml` looks like

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: It worked .. but i cant not understand what was the problem.?

Comment: @SammarAhmad do you know how to accept answer on StackOverflow?

Comment: @SammarAhmad check this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376420

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Because may be your app uses name="AppTheme". So that.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared No action Bar in styles, then no need in manifest just use in manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="YourAppName"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```